# Hat flew into the post!

Tags: bug, winter-bash

I just noticed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612497/uniform-convergence-check-f-n-rightrightarrows-f-and-g-n-rightrightarrows-g) thread, [Praphulla's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/87543/praphulla-koushik) hat is in the middle of the post. Refreshing didn't resolve the issue.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Well, if any hat were going to slip the surly bonds of page-layout, it should be Chuck Yeager's hat.

Comment: That hat didn't fly into the proof, rather, the proof was pulled out of the hat! Here SE is testing animation of the new way to mark "proofs pulled out of a hat". Besides being marked that way to draw attention to them, they will also be added to a special review queue. The goal is to migrate all of these proofs to magic.SE.

Comment: I have been seeing screwy behavior with mathjax too, where it re-sizes or corrupts it, but a page refresh corrects it. I suspect the hat feature is causing this.

Comment: @Amzoti: Ah really? Refresh doesn't work for me (I just refreshed 5 times in a row). The problem still persists in my screen (for the same page linked above).

Comment: I am talking about the corruption to the mathjax (equations), not the persistent hat. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: Right. But for me, that happens all the time ever since new version of mathjax has been deployed. Especially when I just post a question or an answer, there are space misaligning and size issues. Oh well.

Comment: Maybe this is a new issue and it should be reported as a separate issue too as it is very annoying. I assumed it was the hats, but maybe not.

Comment: @Amzoti: It has already been reported [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/spacing-problems) Especially see Jyrki's comment.

Comment: What I am seeing is much worse, it is changing sizes of entire equations, putting them on the wrong part of the screen, mushing them together, corrupting them ...

Comment: @Amzoti: Ohhhh… Yes I do remember seeing that happen once today… You are right… Probably caused by hats.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting. Most other hats are positioned on the page relative to  user's avatar (`position: relative`), but this one is given absolute coordinates, with respect to the upper left corner of the page: (`position: absolute`). Presumably, said coordinates are calculated after the page loads and the hat-adding script can see where the avatar is. Trouble is, the page also has this MathJax thing going on, with several displayed formulas. When they eventually get rendered,  the avatar ends up lower than it was when the hat was positioned. Possible fixes:

1. position all hats relative to avatar
2. add hats after MathJax runs